# How do I use webpack-dev-server to run back-end code?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack to bundle both of my front-end(React) and back-end(Node.js) codes. 
The bundling process was fine. However, when i run "npm run start". The fornt-end code ran fine. But the server-side code was not ran. I tried to run "npm run build" to make sure there isn't any building error. There isn't any error or warning. So i am assuming that the bundling process was fine.

My complete `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-google-charts": "^3.0.8",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.5.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": {
    "/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3001"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.4",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  }
}
```

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        /*Client Side*/
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,"css-loader"]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                template: "./public/index.html",
                filename:"./index.html"
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "[name].css",
                chunkFilename:"[id].css"
            })
        ]
    },
    {
        /*Config for backend code*/ 
        entry: './src/server/server.js',
        target: 'node',
        output: {
            filename: 'server.js'
        },
        externals: [nodeExternals()]
    }
]
```

How do i use webpack command to run both my front-end and back-end code at the same time?

Comment: I assume, that you need to run them in parallel, or one, after another. You could use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all.
So, add new npm script, or additional one, which will run your server main js file and run webpack-dev-server

Comment: @DenisReshetniak i am confused. Since I already bundle my back-end code together with my front-end. They are now in one dist folder, do i still have to run two separate command? thought webpack-dev-server would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the script section of my `package.json` tends to look like. It doesn't use CRA but it's very similar.

```
"scripts": {
  "builddev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --devtool inline-source-map --hot",
  "serverdev": "nodemon src/server.js",
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run builddev\" \"npm run serverdev\""
},
```

where `concurrently` is [this node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).

You'll probably need to proxy your server. Since you're using CRA your webpack config is likely hidden away somewhere so you'll have to add an additional property to your `package.json`:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
```

where 3001 is the port your server is running on.

If you were rolling your own `webpack.config.js` you could add the `devServer` section instead - something like this:

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  proxy: {
    open: true,
    '/apipath': 'http://localhost:3001',
    '/apipath2': 'http://localhost:3001'
  }
},
```

Comment: I actually did use proxy and it is exactly what you had.Please take a look at my update. Thank you

Comment: I see you used nodemon, do I need to use nodemon in my case?

Comment: That doesn't look like my `package.json` proxy. It's simply `"proxy": "http://localhost:port"`

Comment: `nodemon` is used for watching for changes in the code and restarting the server. You don't need to use it but it useful in development.

Comment: I observed that the `serverdev` script is just running the server.js. However, since my back-end code is bundled with my front-end, they are now both under same dist folder. Although they are in separate file, they are in the same build. shouldn't webpack-dev-sever already be enough? Sorry if i am not making sense. First time dealing with webpack.

Comment: shouldn't I be running the  server.js in the dist folder, not server